# Zero W, wireless comms have slowed down recently. Notice lots of retries

Tags: wireless, pi-zero-w

So I use my zero w as a security camera, and lately it is streaming much slower. I rebooted but nothing changed.  The only thing I see is lots of retries in wavemon and /proc/net/wireless.  Any ideas?

wavemon stats:
link quality 64%
signal level -64dBm
mac retries: multiple per second.

│mode: Managed,  access point: BC:64:4B:38:F6:C1
│freq: 2.457 GHz, channel: 10,  bitrate: 19.5 Mbit/s
│power mgt: on,  tx-power: 31 dBm (1258.93 mW)
│retry: short limit 7,  rts/cts: off,  frag: off
│encryption: n/a (requires CAP_NET_ADMIN permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it working better by disabling power mgt, and chaning tx-power to be a bit lower at 25 dBm.